# Unable to run a Shiny app locally that works on the Shiny server

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

My app on the Shiny server here:

https://jphill01.shinyapps.io/HACSim/?_ga=2.90439571.82396853.1682966189-1506360040.1682966189

works fine.

However, the app does not seem to run locally on my system (I'm a Mac user, but I don't think that matters).

The specific error I get is;

```
Navigation containers expect a collection of `bslib::nav()`/`shiny::tabPanel()`s    and/or `bslib::nav_menu()`/`shiny::navbarMenu()`s. Consider using `header` or `footer`   if you wish to place content above (or below) every panel's contents.
```

which suggests the issue lies in my `ui.R` file.

The last deployment of my app to the server was May 2022.

My suspicion is that the code in the shiny package (or any of its variants used for my app) was changed in the last year, rendering my app nonfunctional locally until I implement the necessary fix.

However, I'm sure what exactly needs to be fixed, since my last deployment was successful.

My app uses both `shinydashboard` and `shinyjs`, so maybe it's one of these packages that's the culprit.

Can anyone shed some light and point me in the right direction?